# Dymo twin turbo and crystal reports

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, dymo

I have a winforms vb.net application that uses Crystal reports to print labels to a dymo twin turbo printer. The only thing I cannot figure is how to select either the left or right hand spool in code.

Has anyone come across a way to do this please?

I have downloaded the dymo sdk but this is an awful product, the code in their samples does not run and it isn't clear what references if any I need to add to the project.

Appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

This never worked but I did figure out a workaround.

Using the Dymo app I can create a label layout which is an xml file, I then put some "merge codes" in like {cust_name} then in the vb.net app search for these and replace with the real value.

By the way Dymo is really fussy about the SDK versions, I suggest downloading the sample and looking at the Nuget packages.

Works fine
Graham